# Android Singed APK file : no response from HttpClient / HTTPGetCall

Tags: android, http, networking, response

The Android app was tested in Eclipse and everything works perfectly fine.

As soon as I export a signed APK via Eclipse the app does not receive HTTP requests any more.

What could be the problem??

Comment: Did you use javascript in your app?

Comment: Regenerate signed apk. Sometimes this problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this line before the HTTP requests:

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```